# How to deal with NULL value in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, null

Tried almost dozen of thing with Mysql function (IFNULL,COALESCE,if condition etc) and PHP but nothing work for me. it simple query I want 0 (zero) output if there is no fines against employee. Query works fine when I add emp_id in table(emp_fines).

```
$query_str="SELECT SUM(amount) AS fines FROM `emp_fines` 
WHERE MONTH(P_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND emp_id ='".$em_cod."' 
GROUP BY emp_id";
$query=$this->db->query($query_str);
$record=$query->row();
    
if (is_int($record->fines))
echo "0";
else
echo $record->fines;
```

using codeigniter, it gives below error!!
Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object Filename: backend/dashboard.php eLine Number: 350

Comment: When no rows matched you do NOT receive NULL. You receive empty rowset. So none functions will help.

Comment: If you specify one definite `emp_id` in WHERE expression then GROUP BY makes no sense.

Comment: @Akina hmmm yeah thats why no function working but then how to get 0. if there is no row match. Tried different things in PHP but not working. pls help..

Comment: Check rows amount in output on PHP side. If it is 0 then report 0 else get and report `fines` value.

Comment: just wasted almost 4hrs on it. I wish posted that earlier :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Akina for helping me. Finally below code works

```
        $query_str="SELECT SUM(amount) AS fines FROM `emp_fines` WHERE MONTH(P_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND emp_id ='".$em_cod."'"; //echo $query_str;
        $query=$this->db->query($query_str);
        $record=$query->row();

    if ($record->fines===NULL)
          echo "0";
      else
        echo $record->fines;
```

Answer (score 0):

it should use

```
if(is_null($record->fines)){
 // codes Here
}
```